# mongoimport - treat CSV "Infinity" string literal as string, not as Double value

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I am importing data for a client and have noticed that the string literal `"Infinity"`, when it appears in a CSV file, is treated as a `Double` value rather than an actual string.

This could make sense when the value was not enclosed in quotes, but I believe in this context it should be treated as a string.

Take the following (simplified) CSV input file:

```
ID,Name
1,"Infinity"
```

When imported as follows:

`mongoimport.exe -v --host localhost:27017 --username admin --password password --authenticationDatabase admin -d "infinity-test" -c "test-data" --file C:\test-data.csv --type csv --headerline`

It yields the following result:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.10
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.10
> use infinity-test
switched to db infinity-test
> db.getCollection('test-data').find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a09c48ba7025b2e68885f91"), "ID" : 1, "Name" : Infinity }
>
```

The issue is easier to spot in MongoBooster where it gives the field type:

[image]

Is there a way to force `mongoimport` to treat the literal `"Infinity"` as a string?

Comment: Read about [column types.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption-columnshavetypes), In modern releases you can specify a column type in the import beyond the defaults. FYI even if you used an older MongoDB, there is nothing stopping you installing a latest "tools" package, which is `mongoimport`, `mongodump` etc. These work with all versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to elaborate on Neil's comment, in MongoDB 3.4, `mongoimport` accepts `--columnsHaveTypes` parameter, which specifies the datatype of the field. By default, it guesses the type based on the content.

The full documentation on possible types is https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption-columnshavetypes

For example, you can modify the CSV headerfile to specify that both fields are string instead of numbers:

```
ID.string(),Name.string()
1,"Infinity"
```

and import using `mongoimport --type=csv --columnsHaveTypes ...`